# Continuing reading from a file descriptor in a mex-file

Tags: matlab, mex

I'm trying to pass a file descriptor from Matlab to a mex-function (written in C) to parse a large block of text.
The minimum working code is as follows:

```
#include "mex.h"
#include 
void mexFunction( int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[]) {
   char buf[1024];
   int fd = (int) mxGetScalar(prhs[0]);
   FILE* f = fdopen(fd,"r");
   mexPrinf("%d",ftell(f));
   fgets(buf,1024,f);
   mexPrintf(buf);
}
```

It's called from Matlab/Octave as follows:

```
f = fopen('foo.txt','r');
fgets(f); % do something
disp(ftell(f));
foo(f);
```

When passing a file descriptor after reading some lines with `getline()`, the current file position is about 4KB ahead of the position in Matlab.

I suspect a problem with Matlab buffering the input, but due to performance concerns I can't disable buffering.

Is there a way to have the mex function start at the current position in matlab?

Comment: Can you use `ftell` and `fseek` or should that be implicitly covered by the file-handle? What is `fd` in your code?

Comment: @mbschenkel Calling ftell() on the same file descriptor from Matlab and C returns a larger value in the C code. Calling `fseek(f,ftell(f));` before calling the C function actually works

Comment: Where does this file descriptor come from?  What platform is this on?

Comment: And actually for an MWC the calling Matlab code would also be of relevance...